# resolution of the identity applied to exponential functions

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, greens-function

**Context**

I am working with three-dimensional Green's functions. A Green's function must satisfies
$$
1 = \lim_{\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}\to0 }  \int_{\mathbf{x}^{\prime}-\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}}^{\mathbf{x}^{\prime}+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}} L[G(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{x}^\prime)],
$$

In the problem that I am working, which is a three-dimensional Laplacian operator with cylindrical boundary conditions, this requirement becomes
\begin{align*}
1 
&= 
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} 
\int_{\rho = \rho^\prime -\varepsilon}^{  \rho^\prime +\varepsilon}
\int_{\varphi = 0}^{ 2\,\pi}
\int_{z = 0}^{L} 
\nabla^2 G 
\,
dV.
\end{align*}
After some effort, this requirement reduces to the following integral:
\begin{align*}
1&= 
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}    
\int\limits_{0}^{2\,\pi}
\left[ \frac{\partial  G }{\partial \rho} \right]_{\rho=\rho^\prime + \varepsilon} 
-
\left[ \frac{\partial  G }{\partial \rho} \right]_{\rho=\rho^\prime - \varepsilon} 
\,
\rho\, d\varphi\,dz
\,.
\end{align*}
I now substitute in my Green's function, which I almost positive is correct up to  multiplicative constants (i.e., $k$ in the equation below).  When I substitute in, the requirement becomes
\begin{align*}
1&= 
\int\limits_{0}^{2\,\pi}
\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty
\dfrac{
\left[
a_m\cos{\left(m\,\varphi\right)}
+
b_m\sin{\left(m\,\varphi\right)}
\right]
\left[
a_m\cos{\left(m\,\varphi^\prime\right)}
+
b_m\sin{\left(m\,\varphi^\prime\right)}
\right]
}
{
2\,\pi \left|a_m\right|^2   \,\delta_{m,0}
+
\pi \left(\left|a_m\right|^2 + \left|b_m\right|^2\right) \left(1-\delta_{m,0}\right)
}
\, d\varphi
\\
&\times
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}    
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}    
k\,
\exp{\left(-l\bigl[\left|z\right|+ \left|z^\prime\right|\bigr]\right)}
\,
dl
\,dz
\\
&\times
\lim_{\rho \to \rho^\prime} 
\dfrac{
\begin{bmatrix}
+
\left[
J_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime\right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
-
 J_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
 \,Y_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime\right)}
\right]
\left[
 \frac{dJ_m{\left(l\,\rho \right)}}{\rho}
Y_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
-
J_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
 \frac{dY_m{\left(l\,\rho \right)}}{\rho}
\right]
\\
-
\left[
\frac{dJ_m{\left(l\,\rho \right)}}{dr}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
-
 J_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
 \frac{dY_m{\left(l\,\rho\right)}}{dr}
\right]
\left[
J_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime \right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
-
J_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
\,Y_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime \right)}
\right]
\end{bmatrix}
}
{
 \frac{2 }{\pi\,\rho }\,
\left[
J_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
-
J_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
\right]
}
\,.
\end{align*}
To show that the this equation is consistent, I have to show  a few things. This includes that (derivation not included for pithiness)
$$
\lim_{\rho \to \rho^\prime} 
\dfrac{
\begin{bmatrix}
+
\left[
J_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime\right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
-
 J_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
 \,Y_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime\right)}
\right]
\left[
 \frac{dJ_m{\left(l\,\rho \right)}}{\rho}
Y_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
-
J_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
 \frac{dY_m{\left(l\,\rho \right)}}{\rho}
\right]
\\
-
\left[
\frac{dJ_m{\left(l\,\rho \right)}}{dr}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
-
 J_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
 \frac{dY_m{\left(l\,\rho\right)}}{dr}
\right]
\left[
J_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime \right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
-
J_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
\,Y_m{\left(l\,\rho^\prime \right)}
\right]
\end{bmatrix}
}
{
 \frac{2 }{\pi\,\rho }\,
\left[
J_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
-
J_m{\left(l\,b\right)}
\,
Y_m{\left(l\,a\right)}
\right]
}
=1\,.$$
This also includes that
$$
\int\limits_{0}^{2\,\pi}
\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty
\dfrac{
\left[
a_m\cos{\left(m\,\varphi\right)}
+
b_m\sin{\left(m\,\varphi\right)}
\right]
\left[
a_m\cos{\left(m\,\varphi^\prime\right)}
+
b_m\sin{\left(m\,\varphi^\prime\right)}
\right]
}
{
2\,\pi \left|a_m\right|^2   \,\delta_{m,0}
+
\pi \left(\left|a_m\right|^2 + \left|b_m\right|^2\right) \left(1-\delta_{m,0}\right)
}
\, d\varphi
=
\int\limits_{0}^{2\,\pi}
\delta{(\varphi-\varphi^\prime)}\, d\varphi,
$$
which i explain by the *resolution of the identity*. Ultimately, the requirement on the Green's function is reduced to showing that
\begin{align*}
1&= 
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}    
\left[
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}    
k\,
\exp{\left(-l\bigl[\left|z\right|+ \left|z^\prime\right|\bigr]\right)}
\,
dl
\right]dz
\,. \tag{A}
\end{align*}
So, from here I ask myself the questions that follow.

**Questions**

Q.1. Can I use the resolution of the identity on exponential functions (cf, the the bracketed factor  in Eq. A), such as
$$
\int\limits_{l=0}^{\infty}    
k\,
\exp{\left(-l\bigl[\left|z\right|+ \left|z^\prime\right|\bigr]\right)}
\,
dl
\, ?
$$

Q.2. Why or why not?

Comment: What's your goal in using a resolution of the identity for that integral? I'm a little confused.